# Using Arrow Down Key in Python Selenium (Mac OS)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a Drop-Down Menu on a website and select a specific value.
Since I don't know how to click on an element in a Drop-Down Menu I thought I can let the WebDriver use the Arrow-Down Key several times before hitting the ENTER/Return Button.

I tried the following:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path='/Users/EA/Desktop/chromedriver',options=option)

browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select').click() # OPEN DROP-DOWN MENU

actionsDOWN = ActionChains(browser) ## ARROW-KEY DOWN
actionsDOWN.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform() ## Press ARROW-KEY Down
```

However, it does nothing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the keys to your select element:

```
select_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select')
select_element.click()
select_element.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)
```

though i would really recommend using other methods to find your select element to make your code more readable and flexable. You can find more on this topic here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html